# Validating previous analysis with new data

Tags: statistical-significance, validation

I am interested in trying to validate some results from a previous experiment. The experiment involves selecting probes of interest that separate our two populations of interest, e.g. smoker vs. non-smoker, high protein diet vs. low protein diet.

I have called some probes on an initial data set as significant but what I am interested in is how to statistically validate them in a second set of samples done at a separate time.

Is there a methodology or statistical test to say that there is a difference in a probe on the second set of samples given that they have been called different initially.

One way (I thought of) is to call differences on this new data and see if there are overlapping results. This however, does not take into account the fact the existing information we have.

I am sorry if this is a simple question but I have not been able to find an answer as of yet.